# How can I play local encrypted files on ios which are encrypted with AES

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, avplayer

I am looking for a solution to play the locally downloaded encrypted media files. The server is sending the encrypted media files. I want to play without decrypting the whole file and then write the file at any other place. Files are not downloaded via HLS streaming. Encrypted files are mp3 or mp4 files which are encrypted. Decrypting the whole file first then playing the file causing memory-related issues.

Comment: You want to play back an encrypted media file without fully decrypting it at first?  It doesn't make sense to me.  Besides, you don't tell how media clips are encrypted.

Comment: Media files are encrypted using RNCryptor. Now I don't want to decrypt the whole file and place it at any temp location so as to play via AVPlayer. This is what I want? I want to decrypt the chunks and to play them.

Comment: @ElTomato - AES encryption is encoding chunks of 5 seconds and will be decoded/decrypted at play time. It makes no sense decrypting hole file when live streaming for example. More reading for this subject is HLS and DASH streaming + DRM